# Error when importing WSGIHandler with django

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi

Without any code changing, my django app started throwing an exception while loading the WSGI script. I'm using django 1.3 with python 2.7, and the top-level `.wsgi` is essentially unmodified from the default:

```
import os
import sys

from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'api.settings'
application = WSGIHandler()
```

It started producing these errors on *any* request, as reported by Apache:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=3283): Target WSGI script '/home/beder/webapps/api/api.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
mod_wsgi (pid=3283): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/beder/webapps/api/api.wsgi'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/beder/webapps/api/api.wsgi", line 4, in <module>
    from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
  File "/home/beder/webapps/api/lib/python2.7/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django import http
  File "/home/beder/webapps/api/lib/python2.7/django/http/__init__.py", line 122, in <module>
    from django.utils.http import cookie_date
  File "/home/beder/webapps/api/lib/python2.7/django/utils/http.py", line 7, in <module>
    from email.Utils import formatdate
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/email/__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    __import__(self.__name__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/email/utils.py", line 27, in <module>
    import random
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 47, in <module>
    from os import urandom as _urandom
ImportError: cannot import name urandom
```

I restarted the server, and it now works normally (no errors). I'm at a loss for what to do - I want to make sure this doesn't happen again, but it's not happening now, and I have no idea why that import error appeared.

Comment: I had the same thing happen to me after updating from ubuntu 10.04 to 12.04, and I believe it can happen after updating python through apt-get. Did you do so? I believed this was only supposed to happen in a virtualenv though.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco, I don't think so - I have a managed server with webfaction, and they've always warned me about server migrations/updates in the past. I'll check with them, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you executing Django inside a virtualenv? Did you updated or upgraded your system? If so and you upgraded to Python 2.7 from Python 2.6 for example you need to regenerate the virtualenv:

> $ virtualenv [your-options] [your-django-project-directory]

Comment: Yes, as it turns out, my hosting provider upgraded from python 2.7.2 to 2.7.3. This appears to be a known bug: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2012-March/118233.html

Answer (score 2):

For anyone using webfaction like Jesse and myself to run his django app but is *not* using virtualenv, it can happen that after the upgrade, the custom apache installation for the webapp was never restarted. This means that the stdlib changed but apache still uses python 2.7.2 because its the version it has loaded into memory.

The solution in this case is simple: login to your account via ssh and execute:

```
[username@webXX ~]$ ~/webapps/<webapp-name>/apache2/bin/restart
```

This restarts the web server and causes apache to reload the new interpreter binary.

Answer (score 0):

I also found the same error when I updated Python 2.6.5 to 2.6.8, building from source. I also had built mod_wsgi from source, and initially forgot to recompile mod_wsgi for the new version of Python, and that led to the same error concerning urandom.